# Scroll View not scrolling when a label is added in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

**PROBLEM IS SOLVED **
Solution: Turns out all I had to do was uncheck auto-layout. Thanks guys for the help otherwise!

I have been having this problem and I absolutely hate it.

So I have a navigation controller that leads to another view, a scroll view. In this scroll view there is a ONE LABEL. The label doesn't have any code added to it, no outlets nothing. If I use the simulator then the view doesn't scroll, but when I delete the label from the scroll view it scrolls perfectly. I don't want to add the labels programatically because there is a lot more content I wish to add.

All the scroll views code is perfect, I added this:

```
   [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 800)];
```

Also I tried to add a subview for this label but it still doesn't work. I want to add a label in the story board by dragging not writing the code for it.  What is the problem here like honestly I have such great apps made but this stupid problems makes me so mad!

Comment: I believe with autolayout they size to wrap their contents unless you explicitly state otherwise. Whats the problem with using that code above? One option would be to set contentsize in storyboard if you really just dont want to write code for it

Comment: We need more info than this. Code or storyboard screen shots. Or even better would be a small example that you can put on GitHub. Either of these will help. What are you using to layout the label in the scrollview? Are you using auto layout?

Comment: Usually you can't scroll on a scrollView is either you've disabled it by setting scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO or your scrollView's contentSize doesn't exceed the scrollView's frame size so there is no need to scroll. When you add your UILabel to your UIScrollView (I assume using interface builder), does your Interface Builder add some constraints automatically, say, the UIlabel constraints that forces UIScrollView's 4 edges (top, right, bottom left) to be pinned to the UILabel's 4 edges?

Comment: Omg it works now, turns out I had to uncheck auto-layout thank you guys for your help greatly appreciated!